# For loop with if/else statement not working as expected

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The function I'm struggling with is part of a script that creates folders and copies a certain spreadsheet into each folder 15 times and names them.

I have a loop to create the files and inside of it I have an `if..then..else` statement to use a certain name for the file if `j>10` and another name (else) if it's not.  It always names the file one name and doesn't seem to recognize the if/else statement to change the name if `j` is over `10`.

Basically what I want is to name the file

```
var namedFileCopy = fileCopy.setName(newFileName);
```

if `j` is less than `10` and...

```
var _namedFileCopy = fileCopy.setName("_" + newFileName);
```

if `j` isn't less than `10`.

I'm wondering if I need to add a break in there somewhere, but I'm not really familiar with how to use breaks.

This is the function that is giving me a problem, and you'll find all my code in the snippet following it.

```js
function putFilesIntoFolders(arrayOfFolderNames,theFolderNames,cell) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var theSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var folderType = theSheet.getRange(2,1);
  var cell = folderType.getValue();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("ID");
  var dest_folder  = "";

  var baseFileName = "",
      newfile,
      newFileName = "",
      i=0,
      j=0;

  for (i=0;i<arrayOfFolderNames.length;i+=1) {
    var source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID");
    dest_folder  = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderIds[i]);
    Logger.log('dest_folder' + dest_folder);

    baseFileName = arrayOfFolderNames[i];

    for (j=1; j<16; j+=1) {
      var newFileName = baseFileName + " " + cell + " " + j.toString();
      var fileCopy = file.makeCopy();
      var namedFileCopy = fileCopy.setName(newFileName);
      var _namedFileCopy = fileCopy.setName("_" + newFileName);

      if (j<10) {
          dest_folder.addFile(namedFileCopy);
          source_folder.removeFile(fileCopy); 
      }  else {
          dest_folder.addFile(_namedFileCopy);
          source_folder.removeFile(fileCopy);
      };
    };
  };
};
```

```js
  var folderIds = [];

function onOpen(e) {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Data System Tool')
       .addItem('Create Data System Folders', 'copyAndRenameTemplate')
       .addToUi();
}

function copyAndRenameTemplate() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var theSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rangeOfFileNames = ss.getRange("B4:B");
  var twoD_Array = rangeOfFileNames.getValues();
  var arrayOfFileNames = twoD_Array.join().split(",");
  var folderType = theSheet.getRange(2,1);
  var cell = folderType.getValue();

  Logger.log(folderType);
  Logger.log(cell);
  
//  throw new Error('This is not an error. This is just to abort javascript');
  
  var fldrNamesRng  = theSheet.getRange(4,1,theSheet.getLastRow()-3,1);
  Logger.log('fldrNamesRng: ' + fldrNamesRng);
  
  var folderNames  = fldrNamesRng.getValues();
  Logger.log('folderNames: ' + folderNames);
  
  var oneD_FolderNames = folderNames.join().split(",");
  Logger.log('oneD_FolderNames: ' + oneD_FolderNames);
  
  makeTheFolders(oneD_FolderNames);
  putFilesIntoFolders(oneD_FolderNames);
};

function makeTheFolders(theFolderNames,cell) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var theSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var folderType = theSheet.getRange(2,1);
  var cell = folderType.getValue();
  
  var i=0,
      folderObj;
  
  for (i=0;i<theFolderNames.length;i+=1) {
    folderObj = DriveApp.createFolder(theFolderNames[i] + " " + cell);
    
    folderIds.push(folderObj.getId())
  };
};

function putFilesIntoFolders(arrayOfFolderNames,theFolderNames,cell) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var theSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var folderType = theSheet.getRange(2,1);
  var cell = folderType.getValue();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("ID");
  var dest_folder  = "";
  
  var baseFileName = "",
      newfile,
      newFileName = "",
      i=0,
      j=0;
  
  for (i=0;i<arrayOfFolderNames.length;i+=1) {
    var source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID");
    dest_folder  = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderIds[i]);
    Logger.log('dest_folder' + dest_folder);
    
    baseFileName = arrayOfFolderNames[i];
    
    for (j=1; j<16; j+=1) {
      var newFileName = baseFileName + " " + cell + " " + j.toString();
      var fileCopy = file.makeCopy();
      var namedFileCopy = fileCopy.setName(newFileName);
      var _namedFileCopy = fileCopy.setName("_" + newFileName);
     
      if (j<10) {
          dest_folder.addFile(namedFileCopy);
          source_folder.removeFile(fileCopy); 
      }  else {
          dest_folder.addFile(_namedFileCopy);
          source_folder.removeFile(fileCopy);
      };
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: Close your `for` loop with `}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no issue about your loops, no need to `break;` out of them. 
Your problem occurs in these lines of code:

```js
  var fileCopy = file.makeCopy();
  var namedFileCopy = fileCopy.setName(newFileName);
  var _namedFileCopy = fileCopy.setName("_" + newFileName);
```

The `makeCopy()` method will create a new file object, representing a new file in your Google Drive.

After that, you call the `setName()` method on the `fileCopy` object, which changes the name of the associated file. That's fine, except that you've assigned the return value of the method call to a new variable, `namedFileCopy`. You've now got two variables that reference the same object, because this method simply returns the original object *for chaining*. (Chaining is when we call multiple methods on on object in the same statement; it's only possible if each method returns the original object reference for the next method.)

Next, you call `setName()` on `fileCopy` again, assigning the return value to `_namedFileCopy`; that's the third reference to the exact same object. Oh, and that file - the file that all three object references point to - is now named with an underscore.

After this, your `if..then..else` is doomed to name the resulting file with an underscore. Actually... the file is already named with an underscore, from the third operation above.

Separate concerns some more; you've got to make a decision about a file name, so do that in isolation. Once you've completed that concern, you are ready to manipulate the file, which is a separate concern.

The resulting loop should look something like this:

```js
  for (i=0; i<arrayOfFolderNames.length; i++) {
    var source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID");
    dest_folder  = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderIds[i]);
    Logger.log('dest_folder' + dest_folder);

    baseFileName = arrayOfFolderNames[i];

    for (j=1; j<16; j++) {
      // Determine the name for the new file
      var newFileName =  baseFileName + " " + cell + " " + j.toString();
      // Prepend file name with underscore if j >= 10
      if (j >= 10) newFileName = "_" + newFileName;

      // Copy "file" and apply our newFileName, then move to new destination.
      var fileCopy = file.makeCopy()
                         .setName(newFileName);

      dest_folder.addFile(fileCopy);
      source_folder.removeFile(fileCopy); 
    }
  }
```

(I suspect this is what being said in Alvaz' answer.)

Answer (score 0):

fileCopy.setName() changes the filename property of the file object. You should move your calls to fileCopy.setName() inside of your conditional branches.